# How to mimic XPath 2.0 functions by lxml extension functions?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am following the [lxml documentation on extension functions](http://lxml.de/extensions.html) and want to mimic the [`upper-case`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-upper-case) function in XPath 2.0.

```
import urllib
from lxml import html, etree

ns = etree.FunctionNamespace(None)
ns['upper-case'] = lambda context, s: str.upper(s)

google_page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read().decode('latin-1')
google_page_tree = html.fromstring(google_page)

# text == ['Google.com']
text = google_page_tree.xpath('//a[@id="fehl"]/text()')

# TypeError: descriptor 'upper' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list'
text = google_page_tree.xpath('//a[upper-case(@id)="FEHL"]/text()')
```

It seems it's not the correct way because I see `upper-case` received an empty list `[]`. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with your XPath API but `@id` selects in XPath 1.0 a node-set with a single attribute node and in XPath 2.0 a sequence with a single attribute node. I assume that the `str.upper` method expects a string value so instead of `//a[upper-case(@id) = ...]` try `//a[upper-case(string(@id)) = ...]`. That way the XPath expression should yield a string which the Python function knows to consume.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to mimic xpath 2.0 functions. You can use them with lxml by using `elementpath`.

Just install it with pip, if your python is 3.6+

```sh
    pip install elementpath
```

Then, import both elementpath and lxml.

```py
    import elementpath
    from lxml import etree
    root = etree.XML("<book name='sense and sensibility'/>")
    elementpath.select(root, "upper-case(@name)")
```

This will produce:

```
    'SENSE AND SENSIBILITY'
```

If your xpath returns nodes, the return type is a list of `lxml.etree._Element`. So you can treat `elementpath` as an extension of `lxml`.

Reference:

[elementpath docs](https://elementpath.readthedocs.io/)

[XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Functions and Operators (Second Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/)

[What's New in XPath 2.0](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/03/20/xpath2.html)